# Sereis converge and countable subset

Tags: sequences-and-series

$E$ is the subset of the interval $[0, 1]$, which has the following attribute:
for every $(a_n)$  which $a_n \in E$ for every $n$ and all the elements of $a_n$ are different from each other the sereis $\sum a_n$ converge.

I need to prove that the subset $E$ is countable. Now, I figured out that for
every $\epsilon>0$, $E\cap [\varepsilon, 1]$ is finite because $a_n\to 0$.
I don't know how to proceed from here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You are almost there. That gives you a way of counting the members of $E$: there are only finitely many in $(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}]$

Comment: But if E=[0, 1/(n+1))?

Comment: $(0,1]=(\frac{1}{2},1]\cup(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2}]\cup(\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{3}]\cup\dots$, where the union is countably infinite. The intersection of each of these sets with $E$ must be finite.

Comment: got it! thanks!!